# Python3 send a image .png into a Discord channel using webhook

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, python-3.6, webhooks

I have a python 3.6 script that generates a png image file and I simply want to post this image in a Discord channel at the end of the python script. How can I do so?

It is a surprisingly challenging task as none of the following solutions seem to work

1. Use CV2 to put an image in a json body. The OpenCV library installation is way to painful. Spend 1 hour and still cannot get

`import cv2`

done without an error message.  Simply give up on CV2.

[Unable to import cv2 module (Python 3.6)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50909569/unable-to-import-cv2-module-python-3-6)
[Install of opencv-python-headless takes a long time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64650877/install-of-opencv-python-headless-takes-a-long-time)
[Newbie Python, PyCharm and Anaconda issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65620167/newbie-python-pycharm-and-anaconda-issues)

```
def send_image_to_discord(self, image_file, url):
#   this version requires CV2 which is super painful to install

    
    # this function takes the image and send it to the Discord channel

    img = cv2.imread(image_file)

    string_img = base64.b64encode(cv2.imencode('.png', img)[1]).decode()

    req = {"image": string_img}

    res = requests.post(url, json=req)

    return res

URL = 'Discord channel webhook' 
self.send_image_to_discord(image_file, URL)
```

2. Use Discord.py but that is more for a BOT with await

   ```
   async def send_image_to_discord(self, image_file, discord_channel_id):

        client = discord.Client()

        channel = client.get_channel(discord_channel_id)

        await channel.send('hello')

        await channel.send(file=discord.File(image_file))

   URL = 'discord channel id'
   self.send_image_to_discord(image_file, url)
   ```

Any other ways? Thank you!

Comment: What's the problem with the second method? How do you generate the PNG? Do you have any specific problem?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use discord.py's [SyncWebhook](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=syncwebhook#discord.SyncWebhook). Create a webhook in the channel you want, get the URL, and something like this should work:

```py
from discord import SyncWebhook, File

wh = SyncWebhook.from_url(<webhook url>)
wh.send(file=File(image_file))
```

An upside to this solution is that you don't even need a bot application in the server.